# WebStorm: search does not work

Tags: search, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I know that is used to search : <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd> or Edit | Find | Find in Path
and it worked before, but now always returns the empty set, although I know that what I'm looking for - there is in the project

Maybe someone had this problem?

Comment: What is your `Scope` set to? I've found that IntelliJ likes to sometimes set itself to the `Directory` scope instead of `Whole project` after performing a search.

Comment: I chose the Scope in different ways, even reinstall the program. need to clean karma :)

Comment: please try invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, restart) - does it help?

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same issue. Search kept on saying: "Usage search was cancelled". I invalidated my caches and restarted now it's fine.

Comment: Invalidating cache fixes the same issue in InteliJ Idea as well.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

As lena said, the following should fix it for you:

1. Click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..
2. Click the button "Invalidate and Restart"
3. After restart, try run the search again

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.3. That is also REALLY KILLING my productivity.
I have some problems with SSHFS on Linux - unfortunalety, problems persist and are unresolvable.
I' experiencing disconnects from SSHFS mount. I must invalidate my caches then and restart PHPStorm. My project contains few projects in reality, so indexing last about 10 minutes. Before that, I must click Scope->directory in 'Find in Path' dialog.

Comment: Another note: do not forget to uncheck regular expression when u dont need :)

Comment: I was using the active dev environments Ubuntu VM to search on command line for months. Thanks and I hope it sticks. Could have been switching files with git or what that triggered it I'm not sure. Maybe it was a trial of a newer version?

Comment: Does not hep me. My search works only if the file is directly in the same directory. When I click on the parent directory, search shows no results.

Comment: Argh. There is a checkbox `Recursively` https://www.reddit.com/r/phpstorm/comments/3ty6ld/phpstorm_10_find_in_path_not_working/

Comment: I just had this issue. I tried the fix above to no avail. My double shift was working (searching classes) but searching within a single file, searching an entire directory, etc was broken. I deleted all phpstorm files for the program and re-copied them over and it fixed it. This was after upgrading to 2017.1.2

Comment: I was afraid this was going to clear my local changes from git somehow - it did not. Works perfectly.

Comment: What @milkovsky said! I just had this exact same issue. Mind that the checkbox seems to be a UI button now, see http://imgur.com/a/CWyxz

Comment: This also fixed my PyCharm search (Find in Path) when it stopped returning results for stuff I knew existed.

Comment: So this works, but I have to do it multiple times a day... what would be causing this?

Comment: Doesn't this reset code alignment, spacing and other similar preferences?

Comment: Since Version 2020.3 this option is NOT helping anymore.
Whatever is regularly corrupting those indexes, they get corrupted also when they are recreated.
We will need to wait for a bugfix

Comment: that happened to me as well.Now fully realised  - I copy pasted a folder manually and it just wasnt indexed by ide as it looks. Came back to this upvoted before post once again.

Comment: This also helped me 6 years later when PhpStorm was stuck indexing, in a background task: Updating indexes

Answer (score 26):

For me [*nbaosullivan*'s proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900582/712558) didn't work.

In my case **Recursive(Alt+Y)** options wasn't selected. I selected it and it worked and it will be set as default, you don't need to select it all the time.

[image: See that icon and select it please]

Answer (score 17):

Try this (it helped me in PhpStorm 2019.3.1 when "Invalidate Caches / Restart" did not):

1. Close WebStorm
2. Backup directory `<your project>/.idea/` to anywhere
3. Delete file `<your project>/.idea/modules.xml`
4. Open WebStorm

Comment: in my case there is no file named modules.xml, It has vcs.xml and workspace.xml what should be the approach in this case.

Comment: Had an issue where the WS seemingly lost current workspace folder? Tests were not running, search not working. Removing the whole `.idea` folder and reopening workspace did indeed help.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I had this issue but I think actually WebStorm is only returning the first 100 or so results which all happen to be located in 2 files and thus the other occurrences in other files are not shown.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what was happening for me.  It just seemed like "Find in Files" didn't work because it missed the instances I was searching for.  Limiting the search scope would cause the instances to appear so I knew it wasn't an invalid cache issue.   

Changing the "Maximum number of results" to 1000 resolved this issue for me. 

Here's where it can be found: 
Settings/Preferences => Advanced Settings => Find/Replace

Answer (score 3):

Newer version of Webstorm /PHPStorm automatically exclude some folders. For example vendor folder.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000798990-Vendor-directory-being-automatically-excluded

make sure that folders are not excluded

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed the issue:

1. File
2. Repair IDE...
3. (Follow steps to repair indexes)

After doing this, I was able to search "everywhere" using <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For me unchecking the "Words" option (which searches as a whole word) make it work.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative where I needed to refactor the word "holder" with "owner". Using Webstorm's find did not work very well for me. I decided to use instead the the command line with egrep:

`egrep -Rli [^place]holder ./src` 
*-R (recursive all files in directory including symbolic links)
-l (file name only)
 -i (ignore case)*

I found everything and excluded some instances as well via regex. It is way easier and most accurate.